# Local bzr workspace for openERP module development

Tags: odoo, bazaar, launchpad

We decided that we want to publish our modules on Launchpad so I'm restructuring our module development work space. Up until now we worked in a centralized manner. **We decided to try a distributed style**. So far i been leaning towards a layout similar to this:

1. Repository

   - trunk
   - releases

     - 7.0
     - 6.1
   - dev

     - feature2
     - feature3
   - merged

     - feature1

Although this kind of layout seemed very practical to me **the obvious drawback is that we won't be able to to point the openERP configuration file to a single folder** containing all the modules we are working on.

One idea I thought of was to create a single repository where we put all of our modules and then edit the bzr ignore file to ignore releases, dev, merged folders.

1. Repository

   - module1 (trunk)
   - module2

     - releases
     - dev
     - merged
   - module3

**So I was just generally wondering how are other openERP developers solving this problem?**

Comment: I don't quite get your question. First of all, why being not able to point the OpenERP configuration file to a single folder is a drawback? Second, if you want to put all your modules in one bzr repo, just put all of them under one folder, and make this folder a bzr repo. And you could have multiple branches, for example, trunk, 6.1, 7.0, etc.

Comment: Its a draw back because it would be tedious to edit the config file for each module your working on. So far the only reasonable way to work seems to be a module per branch in a rep.
Thanks for the input